# Operators in infinite dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, vectors

In [page 64](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%2520-%2520Principles%2520of%2520quantum%2520mechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjAkoX887PbAhUR3o8KHbr3BFYQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3t59bGXXAPQE5joxcE1CKZ) of Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics, there are a few lines that leave me doubtful:

> It is worth remembering that $D_{xx'} = \delta'(x-x') $ is to be integrated over the second index ($x'$) and pulls out the derivative of $f$ at the first index ($x$).

In the above lines, $D_{xx'} = \delta'(x-x')= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \delta(x-x')$. Here, $\delta$ is the familiar Dirac-Delta function.

What does "pulls out the derivative of $f$ at the first index ($x$)" mean?

Does it mathematically mean as follows?

$\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \langle x|D|x'\rangle \langle x'|f\rangle \mathrm dx' = \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \delta'(x-x')\langle x'|f\rangle \mathrm dx'$, which is equivalent to $\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \delta(x-x')\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx'} \langle x'|f\rangle \mathrm dx' = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x) \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \delta(x-x')\mathrm dx'$, for the interval of integration is infinitesimal. We are left with the integration of $D_{xx'}$ with respect to the second index.

Comment: Why do you need all this stuff with $\epsilon$ and not satisfied with the simple fact that
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(z-a)f(z)\mathrm dz=-f'(a)=-\left[\dfrac{\mathrm df(z)}{\mathrm dz}\right]_{z=a}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}

Comment: @Frobenius Ah! I get it. I was overthinking this. Terrible. I appreciate this.

Comment: @R004 This supports my answer that the results follow from the definitions and sifting properties of the Delta distribution and its derivative. (The sifting property is sometimes taken as the definition)

Comment: @user45664 you are right. I could not interpret the lines well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re. "What does "pulls out the derivative of f at the first index (x)" mean?"

The sifting property of the Dirac Delta distribution is

$$\int f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a)$$

and for its derivative

$$\int f(x)\delta'(x-a)dx= -f'(a)$$

or

$$\int f(x)\delta'(a-x)dx= f'(a)$$

So for  $\delta'(x-x')$ when its placed under the integral along with $f(x')$ and integrated wrt $x'$ the result will be $f'(x)$. Note that $\delta'(x-x')=-\delta'(x'-x)$ but $\delta(x-x')=\delta(x'-x)$. That's because $\delta'(-x)=-\delta'(x)$.